# Undefined variable and trying to get propery of non-object error prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, php-5.5, prestashop-1.5

> Notice: **Trying to get property of non-object** in /var/www/html/cy_prestashop/modules/taxcloud/taxcloud.php on line 699
>
> Notice: **Undefined variable: smarty** in /var/www/html/cy_prestashop/modules/taxcloud/taxcloud.php on line 699

Im using **prestashop version 1.5.6.2** . How to resolve above this error.

This is my code error occured page,

**Taxcloud/taxcloud.php**: line no 699,

```
$page_name = $psv >= 1.4 && Configuration::get('PS_FORCE_SMARTY_2') == 0 ?
    $smarty->tpl_vars['page_name']->value : 
    $smarty->get_template_vars('page_name');
```

Comment: Hi Kirubanidhi, If you want some help I think you'll have to accept answers on your previous questions or give us some feedbacks. Otherwise I'm not sure we will be inclined to help you again. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry @FlorianLemaitre, I've read too late your comment :(

Answer (score 5):

In PrestaShop 1.5.x the global $smarty var is deprecated.
You have to use:
`$this->context->smarty`
If also that snippet give you problem use this:
`Context::getContext()->smarty`

Comment: @VrushalRaut glad that it helps 